# Simple example of many-to-many relation using Sequelize

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, many-to-many, sequelize.js

I'm trying to build a simple example of many-to-many relation between tables using Sequelize. However, this seems to be way trickier than I expected.

This is the code I have currently (the `./db.js` file exports the Sequelize connection instance).

```
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const sequelize = require("./db");

var Mentee = sequelize.define('mentee', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    }
});

var Question = sequelize.define('question', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    text: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    }
});

var MenteeQuestion = sequelize.define('menteequestion', {
//    answer: {
//        type: Sequelize.STRING
//    }
});

// A mentee can answer several questions
Mentee.belongsToMany(Question, { as: "Questions", through: MenteeQuestion });

// And a question can be answered by several mentees
Question.belongsToMany(Mentee, { as: "Mentees", through: MenteeQuestion });

let currentQuestion = null;
Promise.all([
    Mentee.sync({ force: true })
  , Question.sync({ force: true })
  , MenteeQuestion.sync({ force: true })
]).then(() => {
    return Mentee.destroy({where: {}})
}).then(() => {
    return Question.destroy({ where: {} })
}).then(() => {
    return Question.create({
        text: "What is 42?"
    });
}).then(question => {
    currentQuestion = question;
    return Mentee.create({
        name: "Johnny"
    })
}).then(mentee => {
    console.log("Adding question");
    return mentee.addQuestion(currentQuestion);
}).then(() => {
    return MenteeQuestion.findAll({
        where: {}
      , include: [Mentee]
    })
}).then(menteeQuestions => {
    return MenteeQuestion.findAll({
        where: {
            menteeId: 1
        }
      , include: [Mentee]
    })
}).then(menteeQuestion => {
    console.log(menteeQuestion.toJSON());
}).catch(e => {
    console.error(e);
});
```

When running this I get:

> Cannot add foreign key constraint

I think that is because of the `id` type—however I have no idea why it appears and how we can fix it.

Another error which appeared when the previous one won't appear was:

> Executing (default): *INSERT INTO `menteequestions` (`menteeId`,`questionId`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES (2,1,'2017-03-17 06:18:01','2017-03-17 06:18:01');*
>
> Error: mentee is not associated to menteequestion!

Also, another error I get—I think it's because of `force:true` in `sync`—is:

> *DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mentees`;*
>
> ER_ROW_IS_REFERENCED: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

How to solve these?

Again, I only need a minimal example of many-to-many crud operations (in this case just insert and read), but this seems to be beyond my understanding. Was struggling for two days with this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Migrations

I would suggest you use sequelize [migrations](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/v3/docs/migrations/) instead doing `sync()` on each model. There is a module - [sequelize.cli](https://github.com/sequelize/cli) that allows you to manage migrations and seeds easily. It, in some way, forces a project structure by creating initialization file `index.js` inside `/models` directory of the project. It assummes that all your model definitions will be in this directory. This script iterates through all the model files (each model definition is in separate file e.g. `mentee.js`, `question.js`) and performs `sequelize.import()` in order to assign those models to the sequelize instance - this lets you access them later via `sequelize[modelName]` e.g. `sequelize.question`.

**Note:** when creating migration files remember about timestamps fields - `createdAt`, `updatedAt` and, eventually, `deletedAt`.

### Sync

Personally I use `sync()` only when I run the tests - this may be shown in three steps

1. perform `sequelize.sync({ force: true })` in order to synchronize all models
2. run some database `seeds` (also can be done via `sequelize-cli`),
3. run tests.

This is very comfortable because allows you to clean the database before running tests, and, in order to distinguish development from tests, tests can use different database e.g. `project_test`, so that the development database stays intact.

### Many-to-many

Now let's move on to your problem - m:n relation between two models. First of all, due to the fact that you perform `Promise.all()`, the `sync` can run in different order than you add the functions in it. In order to avoid this situation I suggest you use `mapSeries` feature of `Bluebird` promise, which Sequelize uses and exposes under `sequelize.Promise` (this is also the reason of your last error about deleting parent row - you try to delete `mentees` which is referenced from `menteequestion`).

```
sequelize.Promise.mapSeries([
    Mentee.sync({ force: true })
  , Question.sync({ force: true })
  , MenteeQuestion.sync({ force: true })
], (model) => { return model.destroy({ where: {} }); }).then(() => {

});
```

First parameter of `mapSeries` is array of promises, however the second one is a function which is run with the result of each previously defined promise. Due to the fact that `Model.sync()` results in the Model itself, we can perform `model.destroy()` at each iteration.

After that you can insert some data to the database via `create()`, just as in the example. Now time to fix the *Error: mentee is not associated to menteequestion!* error. It occurs because you have associated `Mentee` with `Question` but there is no association between `MenteeQuestion` and `Mentee` (or `Question`). In order to fix that, after `belongsToMany`, you can add

```
MenteeQuestion.belongsTo(Mentee, { foreignKey: 'menteeId' });
MenteeQuestion.belongsTo(Question, { foreignKey: 'questionId' });
```

Now you are able to add `include: [Mentee, Question]` when querying `MenteeQuestion`. You would also run on another error while doing `toJSON()`, because you do `findAll` which returns array of instances. You could do `forEach()`

```
menteeQuestions.forEach(menteeQuestion => {
    console.log(menteeQuestion.toJSON());
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer. I don't have my laptop with me right now, so I cannot test it. Can you update my code snippet as well and explain in the inline comments what you changed? Thanks again!

Comment: [It worked](https://github.com/IonicaBizau/learning-nodejs/blob/master/sequelizejs/many-to-many.js)—thanks a lot! I'll open a bounty as well! I'd be curious why in the docs they didn't mention about this, did they? What's the *good practice*? Thanks!